# Need help to restructure a Laravel project for develop it further

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Recently I received a Laravel Project which was developed by another developer and I was asked to add some features to it. When I open the project I noticed that the project structure is little bit different and I couldn't run it locally. It has an `index.php` file in the root and there is a different folder called `framework` where the Laravel files are included. I'm kinda new to Laravel and can I know is this approach conventionally valid, and can someone guide me to fix the structure of this project to match the standard Laravel application so I can run it locally. `artisan serve` doesn't work and if I try to run it inside `htdocs` folder it gives a HTTP 500 Internal Server Error.

Root of the project
[image: Root of the project]

Inside framework directory
[image: Inside framework directory]

index.php

```php
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/framework/bootstrap/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__ . '/framework/bootstrap/app.php';
$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Comment: `php artisan --version` should tell you the framework version. Then you can lookup how to upgrade.

Comment: @nice_dev it give an error ``` Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::create() mus  
  t be of the type string, null given, called in /opt/lampp/htdocs/vehicle/fr  
  amework/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/SetReq  
  uestForConsole.php on line 32```. In the composer.json Laravel version is mentioned as 8.

Comment: I don't have a issue with the Laravel version, but with the structure of the project itself. How can I reset that?

Comment: I'm a little baffled with why will it hit Request class if you execute an artisan command on the terminal? Knowing the laravel version will help you solve the folder structure issue. Never worked with 8, so I am afraid I can't help any further.

Answer (score 0):

you are having a different version problems basically. The version that you are trying to run "php artisan serve" is different from the repo.
First of all you need to open both "composer.json" files and compare the:

1. php version
2. laravel version

Then you can decide what is easy to fix, option 1 go to the base repo version, option 2 migrate the base repo to your version.
Consider both options because there are some tricky version to migrate where updating/downgrading automatically is not available.

After that don`t forget to match the booting file path in the "index.php" file you posted.

Comment: My `composer.json` file has these lines of codes `"require": {
        "php": ">=7.4.13",
        "edujugon/push-notification": "^4.5",
        "facade/ignition": "^2.3.6",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
        "kodeine/laravel-meta": "dev-master",
        "kreait/laravel-firebase": "^3.1",
        "laravel-notification-channels/webpush": "^5.1",
        "laravel/framework": "8.*",`

Comment: Ohh i get it! so you dont have a compatibility problem, you have a proyect with PRODUCTION scaffolding. If you wanna to run the server in DEVELOP env. 
If you wanna run local (DEVELOP) you can try to tell the index.php where is you boostrap and app location (just remove the "framework" from all the paths '/framework/bootstrap/...' ). But not warranty to get 100% working app.  Usually you develop with the original laravel structure and then you "build" the scaff. that the hosting server need. Wish it helps :)

Comment: where should I put the frontend code inside `assets` folder?

Comment: Mmm its a bit difficult to tell without reading the whole files (path, fronted framework you using,etc), but seems to be inside the framework folder (in production environment), but remember if you change folder to update the index.php paths